# Find best possible value of R

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a list of values from which I need to calculate the best possible value for R. They are related to one another as follows -

$$K = (234 + R)\cos150$$
$$K = (233 + R)\cos155$$
$$K = (226.5 + R)\cos160)$$
$$K = (224 + R)\cos165$$
$$K = (221 + R)\cos170$$
$$K = (228 + R)\cos175$$
$$...$$

and there are many more such data points in this same format.
How do I find the best possible value of R ?
(I know that both K and R are constants.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite you equation as

$y_1=Rx_1-K$ where $y_1=-234\cos 150$, $x_1=\cos 150$

...

$y_n=Rx_n-K$

and Let $m=R, c=-K$

then you equation becomes
$y_n=mx_n+c$ which is a typical linear regression problem.
You can take the formula from many source to find the best R and K. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)